# WP_List_Table error in Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

After updating wordpress to its latest version I get this error whenever I try to add a new confirmation or notification: function WP_List_Table::get_columns() must be over-ridden in a sub-class.

I can try to add new ones but they're just not saved and when I go back to the notifications/confirmations pages I see the error there.

I tried editing notification.php as recommended in another post I found, but it only fixes the problem for the notifications tab. I still can't add new confirmations.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should look up with the Developers of the plugin. `https://www.gravityhelp.com/support/`

Comment: This issue was fixed in Gravity Forms 1.9.12 during the WordPress 4.3 beta/RC period, you'll want to update to the latest version of the plugin which is currently 1.9.14.

Answer (score 3):

I found the same issue and this is how to resolve it (answer from SunWuKong):

In notification.php, in the class

GFNotificationTable extends WP_List_Table { ...

Add this method:

```
function get_columns() {
    $columns = array(
            'name' => 'Name',
            'subject' => 'Subject'
            );
    return $columns;
}
```